# Behavior disiner + Zenject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

Zenject doesn't work with Behavior Disiner. When injected into Action,injection does not occur.

```
[Inject]
public void Constructor(GameStateHandler gameStateHandler)
{
    gameStateHandler.OnGameStart(() => _isGameStart = true);
    Debug.Log(2);
}
```

Debug does not receive logs of the fact that it enters the constructor method, if I use fields, then it is also null.

I expecting injected into Action. Zenject doesn't work with Behavior disiner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show also the binding stage of your code. You need to have this in place and check that the bindings run. From the [documentation](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject#binding):

"In Zenject, dependency mapping is done by adding bindings to something called a container. The container should then 'know' how to create all the object instances in your application, by recursively resolving all dependencies for a given object."

So for your class, imagine named `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    IBar _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
    }

    [Inject]
    public void Constructor(GameStateHandler gameStateHandler)
    {
        gameStateHandler.OnGameStart(() => _isGameStart = true);
        Debug.Log(2);
    }
}
```

You need to have your bindings previously:

```
public class FooInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<Foo>().AsSingle();
        Container.Bind<GameStateHandler>().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

Everything is explained in the docs. Once you have your `FooInstaller` in place, the `InstallBindings` methods will run when you start your app. That will make the container know what to supply when an instance of `Foo` is requested in the code.

Comment: i did it. And it works on monobehavior but doesn't work on Scripts Behavior Disiner/

Comment: What is "Behavior Disiner"?

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/behavior-designer-behavior-trees-for-everyone-15277
This asse.I think that he himself scripts that he needs. But I'm not sure.